# What do "& 0xFF" and ">>>" shifting do?

Tags: java, bit-shift

I am trying to understand the below code.

The method getKey() returns a string, and getDistance() returns a double. The code is a taken from a class which is meant to hold String (the key) and Double (the distance) pairs.

To be more specific I am unsure as to what the lines that do the shifting do.

```
public void serialize (byte[] outputArray) {

    // write the length of the string out
    byte[] data = getKey().getBytes ();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      outputArray[i] = (byte) ((data.length >>> ((1 - i) * 8)) & 0xFF);
    }

    // write the key out
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      outputArray[i + 2] = data[i];   
    }

    // now write the distance out
    long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits (getDistance());
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      outputArray[i + 2 + data.length] = (byte) ((bits >>> ((7 - i) * 8)) & 0xFF);
    }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Spicy detail: it's bit-shifting, not byte-shifting. Have you looked at the docs to see what these operators do?

Comment: Well... since it's bit shifting by a multiple of 8, he actually is shifting bytes

Answer (score 3):

`>>>` is unsigned shift to right operator. It shifts the sign bit too.

`& 0xFF` retains bits to make a 8-bit (byte) value, otherwise you may have some garbage.

Comment: And you don't get some garbage, you get a *sign-extendet value*.

Comment: @Durandal: Indeed, It's a valid and fine value. Garbage value in the view of final value.

Comment: But if you look at the shifting that occurs in the first for loop isn't the and & operator redundant? 

outputArray[i] = (byte) ((data.length >>> ((1 - i) * 8)) & 0xFF);

0xFF is 255 or 1111111 and, because of the loop, (1 - i) * 8 can be either 0 or 8. 0 & 0xFF is 0 and 8 & 0xFF is 8. 

Also I guess I didn't phrase myself correctly in the question, what I wanted to ask is what is the "point" of the above code. Why is the first loop commented as "// write the length of the string out" -- what does it have to do with storing the length? Why not just store it in outputArray[1]?

Answer (score 2):

Start by reading Java's [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) on bitwise operators.  In short:

`>>>` is an unsigned right shift

`& 0xFF` is ANDing the outcome of `(bits >>> ((7 - i) * 8))` with `0xFF`